# Python string.capitalize() method: What use case(s) did the Python designers have in mind?

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and I just found out about the `capitalize` method on strings. It capitalizes the first letter of a string, and only the first letter. ***It also converts all other characters in the string to lower case.***

What scenario was this method designed for? I'm having a hard time imagining the need for a function that does this. It's possible that sometime in the last 20+ years of programming I have needed such a function, but if I have I don't recall it.

### Capitalizing Names

One thing that comes to mind is the capitalization of names. But it's not true (in English, French and Spanish, at least) that all names (of people, places or anything else I can think of) start with a capital letter and all the other letters are lowercase. So that seems like at best a use case that supports only poor user experiences.

I want to know **what the designers of the language had in mind when they created this method**. That's not really opinion-based, although it may be impossible to know, unless they documented it. Have any of you read any documentation from the Python designers about use cases for this method?

I googled "python string capitalize method why would you need that" every way I could think of and didn't come up with any hits.

Please enlighten me!

Comment: for applications where first character of name is mandatory to be in upper case

Answer (score 2):

It's for when you want to capitalize just the first letter of a string.

The standard library in python contains a huge amount of functionality that the average program will not require - but other programs find extremely handy. If the standard library only included functions that every program would use, then it would not be hailed for being the simple-to-use language that it is.

Comment: Sure, but for most standard library functions I (with my apparently very limited imagination) can thing of tens if not hundreds of usage scenarios. But when would a program need to capitalize the first letter of a string? I want to know what the designers of the language had in mind.

Comment: I like this answer - it answers the question as it was originally phrased. Another way to say it would be, *Just because it's in the standard library doesn't mean it's useful to most programmers.* Good point.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that you have a database (or even a csv) where you have told all your friends to fill in their first and last name. While doing so, some of them did not capitalize the first letter of their last name or first name. But when you want to print them on let's say "list of guests coming to your party", you want to consistently print first letter of their first and last name irrespective of their input, because it's a general norm.

In this situation, you just use capitalize() over firstname and lastname of your csv. Silly analogy though!

Comment: Emily-Jane McDonald might not be too happy about that though :P

Comment: Hahaha! That is what Jean-Paul Gaultier also thiks.

Comment: Exactly! You can't go recapitalizing people's names arbitrarily.

Comment: @skypecakes Sure, I agree! But, this was just an example of its usecase. In special cases such as what me and @Shadow were joking about, one can use `capitalize()` again after splitting by `'-'` or `' '` . I feel  `title()` is more apt for the latter case where there are two words in first name or last name seperated by a space.

Comment: Emily McDonald still won't be happy ;-)

Comment: @skypecakes Hahaha! Damn those Scottish surnames :)